# What is the scope of Rust's static variables?

Tags: rust, static, global-variables

[In Rust global variables are declared with the `static` keyword.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#accessing-or-modifying-a-mutable-static-variable) In C there is a difference between static variables (with translation unit scope) and non-static global variables (with truly global scope). Is it useful and possible to make this same distinction in Rust? If not, why not, and if so, how?

Comment: See [Does Rust have an equivalent to C's static variables?](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6cdcka/does_rust_have_an_equivalent_to_cs_static/dhtya44)

Comment: Of particular note is the fact that `static` has two distinct *and unrelated* meanings in C: as a storage class specifier, it is the opposite of `auto` (which is the original meaning and where it gets the name "static"), but at file scope where `auto` is not allowed, `static` instead acts as the opposite of `extern`. It's the first, original meaning that Rust's `static` derives from; other languages (fortunately) never really picked up the C-ism of using `static` for two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static variables have the same scoping rules as other things in a file. If you want it to be accessible from anywhere, you can make it `pub`, otherwise it will be private:

```
// accessible from inside the crate
static A: f32 = 3.141;

mod secret {
    // accessible from inside this module
    static B: u8 = 42;
}

mod not_secret {
    // accessible from inside the crate
    pub static C: u8 = 69;
}

pub mod public {
    // accessible from anywhere
    pub static D: u16 = 420;
}

// accessible from anywhere
pub static E: u16 = 1337;
```

Note that when you put code in another file, this will be a `mod`, i.e. you could have a file `secret.rs` and put the content of the `secret` module in that file etc.

This means that static variables are by default file specific like in C, with the exception of `static`s in the entry point file (e.g. `A` in the example above, the entry point file is usually `main.rs` or `lib.rs`), these are available in the whole crate. You can make them "truly global" by declaring them with `pub`.

Comment: That's not totally correct to speak of "compilation units" here, since in Rust (unlike C) the unit of compilation process is the whole crate, not the individual module.